# Как создать Notification без всплывающего окна

Tags: java, android, ui, android-notification

Подскажите пожалуйста как создать Notification без всплывающего окна. Например как в google mail - при поступлении письма появляется иконка приложения в верху экрана, но нет всплывающего окна.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void startMyOwnForeground(final String title, final int ico){
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "xxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxx.com";
        String channelName = "iknow";
        NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN);
        chan.setSound(null, null);
        chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_SECRET);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        assert manager != null;
        manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

        notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                .setContentIntent(getPendingIntent())
                .setSmallIcon(ico)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_EMAIL)
                .build();
        startForeground(2, notification);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Как раз недавно была противоположная задача, нужно было показывать heads-up уведомления, а они никак не хотели показываться. В итоге, после того, как я указал id канала `setChannelId(channelId)`, уведомления стали показываться в режиме heads-up. Так что в теории, без id, с низким приоритетом, уведомления будут отображатсья только в статус-баре.

Попробуй такой вариант:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, BaseActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
          new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "blah_blah")
                    .setContentTitle(messageAuthor)
                    .setContentText(messageBody)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_small)
                    .setLargeIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_large))
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```